# How to count individuals of an owl class in Jena?

Tags: java, jena, ontology, owl

I'm working on automatic instanciation of an OWL model with Jena. Since every individual need an unique identifier.

How could I know the number of individual of a given OWL class in order to generate a new `id` for the next individual to instanciate in this Class ?

I've try with the following Jena Java code by using the method `listIndividuals`, Here It is, but It's not working.

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public static int individualSize(Resource res){

        int size = 0;

        ExtendedIterator<Individual> individuals = domainModel.listIndividuals(res);

        while (individuals.next() != null){ size++; }

        return size;
}

static String xmlbase = "http://www.semantic.org/ontologies/exemple.owl#";
OntModel domainModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ProfileRegistry.OWL_DL_LANG);
domainModel.read((new FileInputStream(ontoInPath)), null);

int nextId = individualSize(domainModel.getOntClass(xmlbase+"Event"));

System.out.print(nextId);
```

The Error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.NiceIterator.ensureHasNext(NiceIterator.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.UniqueExtendedIterator.next(UniqueExtendedIterator.java:77)
    at soctrace.Intology.individualSize(Intology.java:225)
    at soctrace.Intology.manageOntologies(Intology.java:124)
    at soctrace.Intology.main(Intology.java:65)
```

Is there any method from the `Jena API` that can help me to do this more easily ?

if no ! How could I correct my code.

Thanks you for any reply !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
while (individuals.next() != null){ size++; }
```

Is not the correct way to use an iterator, what you want is this:

```
while (individuals.hasNext()) {
  size++;
  individuals.next();
}
```

You might also want to close that FileInputStream if Model.read does not do so already.

Furthermore, if you're planning on working with OWL, you will want to look at using [OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) which is an OWL-centric Java API.  Jena is great, but it's more RDF/triples centric which makes it cumbersome (in my experience at least) to use for real OWL-based applications.  You probably also want to look into using a dedicated OWL reasoner such as [HermiT](http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/) or [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet) if you're going to be doing a lot of reasoning in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Micheal for your reply. You guess It well, I have to manage ontologie, by doing stuff like, creating instances, updating the model, creating and adding `Classes`, `ObjectProperties` and even `DatatypeProperties`.  So According to your experience It is easier to manage ontologies with `owlapi` rather than `Jena`? do you have link to initation tutorial on `owlapi` ?

Comment: If you go to the OWLAPI site, you'll see they have probably two dozen examples of how to do the basic things you'd want to do with an ontology via the OWLAPI in their documentation section.  Beyond that, their mailing list is a good place to ask questions.

Comment: also, there is now [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api), that is OWL-API in Jena

Answer (score 2):

If I'm doing the math right you have an off-by-one error anyway. Try:

```
public static int individualSize(Resource res){

    int size = 0;
    ExtendedIterator<Individual> individuals = domainModel.listIndividuals(res);

    while(individuals.hasNext()) {
        individuals.next();
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```